# How to get the selected one instead of latest in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Leave Application that checks when the users request a leave and after approval, it removes the days from the total amount they have left in the database the problem is the leave is taken only the latest so if 2 people were requesting at the same time it would take it for both the same amount because it's only taking it from the latest which is here in the User Model

```
public function leaveBalance($id)
    {
        $leave =new Leave;
        $daysUsed= $leave->numberOfDays($id);
        $days_granted = User::where('id', $id)
        ->latest()->first();

        $leave_days_granted = $days_granted->leave_days_granted;
        return $leave_days_granted - $daysUsed;
    }
```

And here in the Leave Model

```
 protected $dates = ['from', 'to'];

     public function numberOfDays($id)
     {

         $datesx =Leave::where('user_id', $id)
         ->latest()->first();

         $from =$datesx->from;
         $to =$datesx->to;

         $datetime1 = new DateTime($from);
         $datetime2 = new DateTime($to);

         $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
         $days = $interval->format('%a');//now do whatever you like with $days
         return $days;
     }
```

As you can see it's taking it from the ->latest()->first(); but I don't know another way to select it and thus why I need help I would appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Tip (not related probably): you can use `User::find($id);` instead of `User::where('id', $id)->latest()->first()`

Comment: Ill test this out and let you know

Comment: Yeah it works for finding the user(not related to the problem I asked)

Answer (score 0):

`User::where('id', $id)->first();`

Comment: No that didn't help it just does the same thing

Comment: Try this `User::where('id', $id)->orderby('id', 'desc')->first();`. If two persons are applying leave at same time and approved, there must be a change in `date time` column name `updated_at`. You can check with that also.

Comment: It's more like when I accept the leave of the person before last he gets the same number as the person who is last, I tried that but it's still the same